Ordering in the django Admin by related manytomany field
This is my models.py:
class Person(models.Model):

    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    forename = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class PersonRole(models.Model):
    ROLE_CHOICES = [
    ("Principal investigator", "Principal investigator"),
    [...]
    ]
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, max_length=30)

class Project(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=PersonRole)

    @admin.display(description='Principal investigator')
    def get_PI(self):
        return [p for p in self.person.filter(personrole__person_role__contains="Principal investigator")]

Each project can have one or more persons with the role set to 'Principal Investigator'. I am already showing a 'Principal Investigator' column in my Admin backend for the projects page with list_display = ("title", "get_PI"). I would like to add ordering to this column. How can I do that? If I add get_PI to ordering django will complain that get_PI is not an existing field.
This is my attempt, which is not working:
admin.py
class ProjectAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('title','get_principal_investigator')
    def get_principal_investigator(self, obj):
        return self.get_PI

    get_principal_investigator.admin_order_field = "get_PI"
    get_principal_investigator.short_description = "Principal investigator"

